# Holomorphic function and real part of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

We have  $f : U \rightarrow C$.
$f$ is holomorphic on $U$ ; the question is :
if $f$ is holomorphic on $U$, is $Re(f)$ holomorphic on $U$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $g:U\to \mathbb C$ only attains real values, but is not a constant, can it be holomorphic (hint: Cauchy-Riemann equations).